# How do I disable IDataErrorInfo & DataAnnotations Validation on load

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

I am writing a WPF application with a MVVM approach, and I am using IDataErrorInfo and DataAnnotations to validate input data. Just like this:

**ViewModel**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// User
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "not blank")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "between 6 and 20")]
    public string UserID
    {
        get
        {
            return _adminInfoModel.UserID;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_adminInfoModel.UserID != value)
            {
                _adminInfoModel.UserID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UserID");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "not blank")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "less than 100 character")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _adminInfoModel.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_adminInfoModel.Name != value)
            {
                _adminInfoModel.Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    //many properties here....

    //implement the IDataErrorInfo interface
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            ValidationContext vc = new ValidationContext(this, null, null);
            vc.MemberName = columnName;
            List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            bool result = Validator.TryValidateProperty(this.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(this, null), vc, results);
            if (results.Count > 0)
            {
                return results[0].ErrorMessage;
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
<TextBox Name="UserIDTB" Text="{Binding UserID, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
<TextBox Name="NameTB" Text="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

**The Problem is:**

When I open this view, Because the ViewModel implement the IDataErrorInfo interface,  the application will validate the properties at once. Some properties use RequiredAttribute validation. So the application will point out blank error when opening the windows immediately. Like this：
[image: The View]

How can the application skip validating properties when open the windows at once? Another way, How can the application validate the RequiredAttribute when click the submit button?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Will I know, but how?

Answer (score 2):

This is always little bit tricky. There are two approaches:

1. Foreach property create another boolean field, or dictionary entry to indicate, whether the property should be validated. In setter of each property, set the field to true. if the property has not been set, then don't return an error. You will also need validate method, that will validate all properties.
2. Use INotifyDataErrorInfo, you notify the view when an error occurs :

here is example:

```
public class MyViewModel : ValidatableBase
{
    [Required]
    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get { return _someProperty; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _someProperty, value); }
    }
}

public abstract class ValidatableBase : BindableBase, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _propertyErrors = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    protected override bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        var result = base.SetProperty(ref storage, value, propertyName);
        var error = ValidateProperty(propertyName, value);
        SetError(propertyName, error);
        return result;
    }

    private void SetError(string propertyName, string error, bool notify = false)
    {
        string existingError;
        _propertyErrors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out existingError);
        if (error == null)
        {
            if (existingError != null) _propertyErrors.Remove(propertyName);
        }
        else
        {
            _propertyErrors[propertyName] = error;
        }

        if (existingError != error)
        {
            OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }

    public virtual bool Validate()
    {
        var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties)
        {
            var error = ValidateProperty(property.Name, property.GetValue(this));
            SetError(property.Name, error, true);
        }
        return HasErrors;
    }

    public void Validate(string propertyName, object value)
    {
        var error = ValidateProperty(propertyName, value);
        SetError(propertyName, error, true);
    }

    protected virtual string ValidateProperty(string propertyName, object value)
    {
        if (propertyName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");

        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(this);
        validationContext.MemberName = propertyName;
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (Validator.TryValidateProperty(value, validationContext, validationResults))
        {
            return null;
        }
        return validationResults[0].ErrorMessage;
    }

    protected virtual void OnErrorsChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = ErrorsChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)) yield break;
        string existingError;
        if (_propertyErrors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out existingError))
        {
            yield return existingError;
        }
    }

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get { return _propertyErrors.Count > 0; }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Implement INotifyDataErrorInfo in your base view model and add an isValidating bool field.  In your GetErrors(string propName) implementation, first check isValidating and return early if false.

You should also add a Validate() method that sets isValidating to true and kicks off a full object validation with Validator.TryValidateObject().  Call Validate() when the user clicks OK and from then on all property modifications will update validation.